# Video using Bitmap not working in chrome - EaselJS

Tags: google-chrome, video, bitmap, easeljs

im using easelJS for a HTML5 project
the problem is that i have put a video element which is loading and playing fine
when i try to add it to a EaselJS stage using

```
var v = document.getElementById('StartingVideo');
                var vBmp = new _.Bitmap(v);
                stage.addChild(vBmp);
                v.play()
```

it works fine in ie9 and the video is played but not in chrome. 
in chrome the actual video in the video element plays fine but nothing is displayed in the `canvas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting a video overlay on top of the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

Code below works for me:

```
        var video =  document.getElementById("sourcevid");
        var bitmap =  new createjs.Bitmap (video);
        stage.addChild (bitmap);
```

the only thing that Im currently stuck with is the dynamic change of video height/width

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to solve the video width problem?